# Functional tests of nested routes on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app with the following nested route:

```
resources :games do
  collection do
    get :all
    get :unassigned
  end
  resources :messages
  resources :comments
end
```

A Game has many comments, and a Game also has many messages.

I am expecting that "/games/1/comments" routes to the index action on the comments controller, and sets `:game_id => 1` in the params hash.

Everything is working fine in the app. However, my route tests are failing and I can't figure out why.

When I try this:

```
assert_routing({:path => "/games/1/messages", :method => :get},
  { :controller => "messages", :action => "index", :game_id => 1})
```

I get this:

```
  2) Failure:
test_route_one(MessagesControllerTest)
    [actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:52:in `assert_recognizes'
     actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:120:in `assert_routing'
     test/functional/messages_controller_test.rb:106:in `test_route_one'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:67:in `__send__'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:67:in `run'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:65:in `run']:
The recognized options <{"action"=>"index", "game_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"messages"}> 
did not match <{"action"=>"index", "game_id"=>1, "controller"=>"messages"}>, 
difference: <{"game_id"=>1}>
```

When I try this (note the quoting on `:game_id`) :

```
assert_routing({:path => "/games/1/messages", :method => :get},
  { :controller => "messages", :action => "index", :game_id => "1"})
```

I get this:

```
  3) Failure:
test_route_two(MessagesControllerTest)
    [actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:90:in `assert_generates'
     actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:127:in `assert_routing'
     test/functional/messages_controller_test.rb:111:in `test_route_two'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:67:in `__send__'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:67:in `run'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
     activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:65:in `run']:
found extras <{:game_id=>"1"}>, not <{}>
```

Also tried this:

```
assert_routing({:path => "/games/1/messages", :method => :get}, {:controller => "messages", :action => "index"}, {}, {:game_id => "1"})
```

Response:

```
The recognized options <{"action"=>"index", "game_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"messages"}> 
did not match <{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"messages"}>, difference: <{"game_id"=>"1"}>
```

I think, somehow, I'm getting hung up on the syntax for testing the routing on nested resources. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assert routing does two things (in that order)

- `assert_recognizes`
- `assert_generates`

So your test-case 2 gets one step further / performs better.

Now, `assert_generates` checks whether `url_for` returns the url you give it.

```
url_for(:controller => "messages", :action => "index", :game_id => "1")
# should return: /games/1/messages
```

But according to the exception, it returns `/messages?game_id=1` (`game_id` as the extra). This should/can only happen, if you have a `resources :messages` rule *before* your `resources :games`. If that's the case, move it behind, so that the nested rule comes first.

Comment: Yep, I duplicated OP's setup and added `resources :messages` before the nested block and got the same error. Good find.

Comment: Yep, that looks like the case for me as well. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
assert_routing({:path => "/games/1/messages", :method => :get}, {:controller => "messages", :action => "index"}, {}, {:game_id => "1"})
```

Comment: That didn't work either... I'll edit my original question to add your suggestion and what it generated.

Comment: Drat! The documentation seems pretty specific! http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html